# Get items in a folder using Core Service

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Using Tridion Core Service, how can I get all the items in a folder?

Comment: Please post the code you have tried - there are lots of Core Service examples here on SO already

Answer (score 14):

You need a filter (OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData).

Then you need to call client.GetList(folderId, filter) to get the list of items in that folder.

```cs
OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData filter = new OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData();
foreach (XElement element in client.GetListXml("tcm:3-640-2", filter).Nodes())
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.Attribute("ID").Value);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A good example on how to use the Core Service which contains all sorts of read operations (like reading a single item and getting a list of items) is shown in the following eXtension on SDL Tridion World: [Item Selector Custom URL](http://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/itemselector.aspx)

The download on SDL Tridion World comes with complete source but this can also be found directly on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/sdl-tridion-world/source/browse/#svn/Item%20Selector/trunk/SDLTridion.Examples.ItemSelector) where it is hosted as an open source solution. The actual Core Service code can be found in the `UserControls/TridionTreeView.ascx.cs` Class.